# os x getUserMedia gain control is reducing a constant input signal over time

Tags: javascript, audio, microphone, getusermedia

I'm trying to build a simple fourier transform program using HTML and javascript for a class.  I have OS X Catalina, and I'm using Chrome, and grabbing the microphone (at least I think I am).

The javascript for getting the stream setup is:

```
    let constraints = {
    audio: {
        echoCancellation: false,
        autoGainControl: false,
        channelCount: 2,
        noiseSuppression: false,
        sampleRate: my_sampleRate,
        sampleSize: 16,
        volume: 1.0
        },
    video: false
    };

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(spectrum).catch(console.log);
let AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
let audioCtx = new AudioContext({sampleRate: my_sampleRate});
let analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
analyser.fftSize = my_samples;
analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0;
audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream).connect(analyser);
let data_raw = new Uint8Array(analyser.fftSize);
```

Then I set an interval and in the function that's called, I grab the raw data stream:

```
analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(data_raw);
```

The code to make the FFT (I know, I could use the built-in analyzer and getByteFrequencyData but I don't want to use that) is straight forward.  When I test it with a 1kHz signal, it shows up in the right place but then fades away.  It's as if something is doing an AC filtering over a relatively long period.

Any ideas on how to get rid of this?  Note that OS X Catalina still has that pesky "feature" where the noise suppression option that used to be in the Preferences/Sound for the microphone is no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

Upon more investigation...I think part of my problem was normalization to make an FFT histogram.   The normalization was increasing, so the peak was decreasing.  But I noticed that when I inject a pure sine wave at 1000 Hz, I see a clear peak in the FFT where it should show up however it starts out at some value and quickly falls within a few seconds to something stable.   So the hardware (or the analyzer?) is doing something I don't understand.   Anyone have a suggestion?